# Incorrect file sizes in /procfs and Incorrect values in /proc/[pid]/stat

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

The ls -l /proc command gives file size 0 for all files in /proc dir.

## ls -l /proc/

dr-xr-xr-x    7 root     root             0 Dec 31 17:23 1

dr-xr-xr-x    7 root     root             0 Dec 31 17:24 10

dr-xr-xr-x    7 root     root             0 Dec 31 17:24 103

dr-xr-xr-x    7 root     root             0 Dec 31 17:24 105

```
  where is this file size calculated in kernel?

 And also the /proc/[pid]/stat has junk characters. Because of this all processes are not listed in ps command output. But the /proc/[pid]/status has valid information.
```

## cat /proc/1/stat

'Ð3 0 0 0 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 9688 403/ 01607 1 269 7 41 20 0 1 0 12 Í7/60 109 2ÿp9 65536 403/ Øß9¾ ØÝ;¶ Cù7² 0 0 0 @

## cat /proc/2/stat

2 (kthreadd) S 0 0 0 0 -1 00.4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 12 0 0 2ÿp9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2ÿp9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

## cat /proc/112/stat

112 (telnetd) S 1 112 112 0 -1 Ô,",0 124 0 1 0 3 27 0 0 20 0 1 0 942 7136 104 2ÿp9 65536 @6136 U?9¶ T?=¶ Jý7¶ 0 0 /(25 d4288 0 0 0 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 @3840 @6136 C6608
#

```
Where all processes stat files are written with values in kernel source code?
```

Answer (score 0):

The flags field has junk chars. Because of this, the cat output has junk chars. I am using 3.4 kernel. Where is this flag field filled in stat file?.

## hexdump -vC /proc/1/stat

00000000  31 20 28 69 6e 69 74 29  20 53 20 30 20 31 20 31  |1 (init) S 0 1 1|

00000010  20 30 20 2d 31 20 d4 2c  22 2c 30 20 38 38 20 31  | 0 -1 .,",0 88 1|

00000020  38 39 34 20 31 37 20 37  20 30 20 32 37 31 20 37  |894 17 7 0 271 7|

00000030  20 34 32 20 32 30 20 30  20 31 20 30 20 31 32 20  | 42 20 0 1 0 12 |

00000040  cd 37 2f 36 30 20 31 30  39 20 32 ff 70 03 39 20  |.7/60 109 2.p.9 |

00000050  36 35 35 33 36 20 85 34  30 33 2f 20 64 dc 91 3d  |65536 .403/ d..=|

00000060  ba 20 64 db 90 3e bc 20  43 18 f9 37 b2 20 30 20  |. d..>. C..7. 0 |

00000070  30 20 30 20 40 0d 27 d0  33 20 30 20 30 20 30 20  |0 0 @.'.3 0 0 0 |

00000080  32 30 20 30 20 30 20 30  20 30 20 30 20 30 20 84  |20 0 0 0 0 0 0 .|

00000090  39 36 38 38 20 85 34 30  33 2f 20 86 30 31 36 30  |9688 .403/ .0160|

000000a0  0a                                                |.|

000000a1